# Custom TableViewCell redraws layer when scrolling UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, scroll

I have tableView with Custom TableViewCell.

TableViewCell has a progress bar. Each progress bar is set with CellForRowAt method. It initializes and updates correctly.

The problem is when I scroll the tableView very quickly, the progress bar layers animate and settle back to their correct options after a second.

How do I stop the cell from animating the layers every time I scroll the tableView.

Comment: You could set a flag in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`. Then implement `willDisplay` and enable the animation based on the flag.

Comment: This is a tableView and not a scrollView

Comment: `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Gotcha. So the scrollViewWillBeginDragging with go as tableView delegate method? and the willDisplay is a tabeView method that sets the flag in TableViewCell?

Comment: Yes, `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` (and similar methods) go to the delegate. `willDisplayCell` is also a delegate method. You set the flag in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and inspect it in `willDisplayCell`.